# TS2345 when passing argument to resolve()

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, es6-promise

I'm trying to locally run the unit tests for https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss, but I'm getting an error:

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'Stats | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stats | PromiseLike<Stats>'`

[The line it's referring to](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/blob/master/packages/purgecss-webpack-plugin/__tests__/index.test.ts#L16) calls the `resolve()` callback of a promise with a potentially undefined argument. However, VSCode seems to indicate that the type signature for the argument to `resolve()` includes `undefined`, so it shouldn't be throwing a type error. Is there any good way to debug this more, or see authoritatively the type signature for `resolve()`?

This is the code block that's throwing a type error:

```
function runWebpack(options: Configuration): Promise<webpack.Stats> {
  const compiler = webpack(options);
  return new Promise<webpack.Stats>((resolve, reject) => {
    compiler.run((err?: Error, stats?: Stats) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      if (stats?.hasErrors()) reject(new Error(stats.toString()));
      resolve(stats); // error TS2345: Argument of type 'Stats | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Stats | PromiseLike<Stats>'
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Not sure how did you see this error. It looks fine since the `PromiseConstructor` defined very clear around the param `resolve` should takes including `undefined`

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question here. Users shouldn't need to visit an off-site link to be able to answer or to understand any answers.

Comment: "*VSCode seems to indicate that the type signature for the argument to resolve() includes undefined*"  it's exactly the opposite `stats` is an optional parameter, so it's possible to *not* pass it in in which case `stats` will be `undefined`. The error is telling you - you cannot pass something that might be `undefined` as it's not an expected result of the promise.

Answer (score 1):

> VSCode seems to indicate that the type signature for the argument to `resolve()` includes `undefined`

This is not Visual Studio Code but the TypeScript compiler. Since you've declared `stats` as an optional parameter of type `Stats` that indicates that it's possible to *not* pass that parameter, so the real type is `Stats | undefined`. However, since you use `new Promise<webpack.Stats>` this constrains the value possible from resolving this promise to be `Stats`, never `undefined`.

There is not enough information for TypeScript to conclude that `resolve(stats)` would only be called if `stats` is *not* `undefined`. You should re-structure your conditionals to exclude the `undefined` value:

```typescript
compiler.run((err?: Error, stats?: Stats) => {
  if (err) reject(err);
  if (stats)
    if (stats.hasErrors()) reject(new Error(stats.toString()));
    else resolve(stats);
});
```